# Ubuntu 12. 04 Android Studio will not load

Tags: arm, chromebook

Android Studio 0.2.2 won't load with JDK-8(build 1.8.0-ea-b102) on a Samsung ARM Chromebook with 32 bit Ubuntu12.04. I have tried older JDKs no luck.

/Downloads/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh
WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.

```
     ITS KNOWN TO HAVE PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS ISSUES!
     SWITCH TO THE ORACLE(SUN) JDK BEFORE REPORTING PROBLEMS!
```

NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
         please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
         See http://ow.ly/6TuKQ for more info on switching default JDK.

Press Enter to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Do what it mentions! Change your Java installation to Oracle, [here are some instructions](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html).

Comment: Yea been there - got the T-shirt.. Unfortunately it's not that simple, that JDK build is compiled for a Intel vs. ARM. [Setting up oracle-java7-installer (7u25-0~webupd8~1) ...
Please report to author unsupported platform 'armv7l'.]

Comment: I didn't even realize those things were supposed to be able to run anything other than their browser. Carry on, then.